# What amps would I need for a variac fan controller?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, fans

I'm looking for a variac controller for a fan. I found one, but it's available in different models based on amps.

How do I work out which controller would be the best one for my fan? My fan specs are: VK150, 230V, 80W

How can I work out the required amps needed to run the fan on a UK power supply?

Comment: Also, fan speed controllers are generally *not* variacs these days -- they're solid state phase controllers instead.

Answer (score 2):

Current (A) = Power (W) / Voltage (V)

In your case, power is 80 W and voltage is 230 V, so the current the fan draws is 0.34 A. Get a controller which can handle at least that much current.